# Using DataTables, make search input responsive like the associated table

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, datatables, pug

I'm using DataTables, and would like to make the input / search box responsive.

I can increase the size etc with `width` however want the search box to be responsive like the table.

What CSS needs to be applied to make the search input responsive?

Currently applied CSS:

```
input[type=search], select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 3px solid #ccc;
    border-color: #004c88;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size:25px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Current DataTable:

```
var now = new Date();
$(`#clients`).DataTable({

    dom: `Bfrtip`,
    buttons: [
        {extend: `copyHtml5`, title: `Heard Phrases ${now}`, text: `Copy to Clipboard`,exportOptions: {columns: [0,1,2,3,4]}},
        {extend: `excelHtml5`,  title: `Heard Phrases ${now}`, text: `Export as Excel`,exportOptions: {columns: [0,1,2,3,4]}},
        {extend: `csvHtml5`,  title: `Heard Phrases ${now}`, text: `Export as CSV`,exportOptions: {columns: [0,1,2,3,4]}},
        {extend: `pdfHtml5`,  title: `Heard Phrases ${now}`, text: `Export as PDF`,exportOptions: {columns: [0,1,2,3,4]}}
    ],
    'order': [[ 0, `desc` ]],
    'bLengthChange': false,
    'iDisplayLength': 50,
    language: {
        'search' : `` /*Empty to remove the label*/,
        searchPlaceholder: `Search clients `
    }

});
```

[image: Search box]

Comment: What kind of behaviour are you expecting of the searchbox?

Comment: Simply that it behaves in the same manner as the associated table - That it flexes with the browser window rather than having a fixed width.